# How to export interfaces from maven project as new artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that creates a JCA connector (.rar file). Now to use this connector in another project I build this thing for, I want to import the interfaces for the connector.

Can I somehow add a build target to the connector pom.xml, which creates a new maven artifact with just the interfaces from the connector project (lets say connector-interfaces)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven has a strong rule, that 1 project -> 1 artifact. I suggest to split your project:

```
connector
+ pom.xml
++ connector-interfaces
+++ pom.xml
++ connector-impl
+++ pom.xml
```

The pom.xml of the connector would contain 2 modules:

```
<modules>
  <module>connector-interfaces</module>
  <module>connector-impl</module>
</modules>
```

In the module `connector-impl`, you will need to add a dependency on `connector-interfaces`. Add this in the `pom.xml` of `connector-impl`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>connector-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use the maven release plugin, add this to the parent pom:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

That way, maven will only ask for the version 1 time when you release.

Comment: Hm that sounds right, one question left: do I have to add dependencies in connector-impl/pom.xml to include connector-interfaces, when both are wrapped in this parent project?

Answer (score 2):

Although @WimDeblauwe is suggesting a best practice and it would probably be best to follow it his way, there is another way you can accomplish this.  There is an [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) that can be used to do this.  Normally it's meant to package your whole project in one jar, but it can also be used to make a subset of classes and make a jar out of that.

It can be a little tricky though.  To do it you'll probably need to create a custom descriptor and reference [this documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) to see how to format your descriptor file.  Here's an example from the documentation of how to point to a custom descriptor:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        [...]
</project>
```

In that `src.xml` file you'll want to `<excludes>` all classes except for the interfaces and set `<includeDependencies>` to false.

Comment: Thank you for showing a way of what I originally asked. But as you said, I will choose the best practice way shown by @WimDeblauwe.